# How to unlock an unnamed semaphore in C for multiple waiting threads?

Tags: c, semaphore

I have an unnamed semaphore initialized to zero.
N threads are waiting on that semaphore, until they should be able to start working.
When the main thread wants to signal all of them that they can start, it has to loop on sem_post() for N times.
Is there an easiest way to do it? Something like the broadcast in conditional variables?
I have to mention that this is an exercise that allows me to only use semaphores, so a sophisticated idea is needed.

Comment: Whenever possible, *show code*. Then explain what the problem with the code is. This helps give important context, especially, in this case, *what threading tools you're using*.

Comment: you can use mutex if you want to release all resources at the same time. you must use semaphore if you have a resource with different capacity.